# Header file is missing from the theme files in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, header

As we have to add this tag

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`

for the site to become responsive , but i am currently using a theme , in which i could not find a header file, any alternative on how to solve this problem, or should i just create a new header file.

Comment: I'm not sure how anyone can help you with the details you have provided. Are you using a child theme? Is the theme outputting a `<head>` tag? If so, then you need to search the theme files for that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following strings to your functions.php file:

`add_action('wp_head', function(){
  ?><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /><?php
});`

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery to do that :P

jQuery('').appendTo('head');